# webDriver.Chrome() can't get url with query string

Tags: python, image, selenium, get, selenium-chromedriver

I have code to download image with query string url, code as below, what can I do to solve this problem?

```
urlImage = "http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
driver.get(urlImage)                           <- Error Here
imgBase64 = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
imgBytes = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgBase64))
imgBytes.seek(0)
imgData = PIL.Image.open(imgBytes)
if rotationAngle != 0: imgData = imgData.rotate(rotationAngle, expand=True)
imgData.save(pathImage)
```

Exception:

```
self.run()
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
driver.get(urlImage)
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
raise ResponseNotReady(self.__state)
http.client.ResponseNotReady: Idle
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works perfectly fine. I am using 2.53.5 selenium and 56.0 version of chrome? can you mention you chrome and selenium version. Also, are you able to open any other website?

Comment: I tried both Mac and Windows, version in Windows is `3.0.2` and `56.0.2924.87`, Mac selenium is also above `3.0`, I can tell you tonight if real want to know..

Comment: Can you try downgrading the Firefox version. Not sure, but if this is due to compatibility issue, it might resolve. As everything works fine with Selenium 2.

Comment: I tried Firefox but it seems can't scrape JavaScript, is this right?

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question after you get answers, since it makes the answers meaningless. If you have follow-up questions, post them as new questions. You might also want to have a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

How about using `requests` instead of using `selenium`?

If you have specific URL to get resources, you can just use `requests.get`.

> make sure you have installed `requests` with pip

here's the code:

```
import requests
import shutil

url = 'http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg'
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg', 'wb') as file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, file)
```

Comment: I modified code as above, how can I rotate image if use your code?

Comment: check this link :)

Comment: by the way, `shutil.copyfileobj` will save image to local, I want to rotate it before save...